# Restrict Web App Access to a set of tablet computers

Tags: security, tablet

A client has asked for additional security for a web app which would allow only company owned and approved tablet computers (brand not yet known) to connect to a PHP web app.

The app will be un/pw protected but the company would like to prevent all access except via the tablets.

MAC addresses would be great for this but these will be used in the field and use a myFi portable wifi to connect to the server so the MAC address will not be available.

Can anyone point me to a sound method for this secondary validation?

Comment: What are you/company trying to protect against? Is it misuse of the server? Who is potential attacker? If the tablet is lost while in the field, everyone can pick it and copy information from it (or just use it to access the server). So the question is not so simple to be answered without serious analysis.

Comment: Point taken Eugene.  They want to provide their sales team with access to mapped leads in the field with real time updates from headquarters but they don't want it to be accessible by browsers other than those on the tablets.  Pointy haired boss has not revealed any reasoning for this but added it as a part of spec for job.

Comment: I think mutual SSL authentication with OCSP validation of client certificates on the server would work. OCSP validation is needed to ensure that if the tablet is stolen, the certificate can be quickly revoked and blocked on the server.

Comment: Since he owns the tablets and the server, don't use a CA at all. Use self-signed certificates and have each side only trust the ones deployed to the other side. Then, if a client gets stolen, you can just revoke the trust for that client-side cert on the server; no third-party (or money paid to them) needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best solution here would be to deploy mutually-authenticated SSL between your client tablets and your server. You can use self-signed certificates here so you don't need to buy any from a CA. This will ensure that your server only accepts requests from tablets that have the client-side certificate (configure your server to only accept the self-signed client certificates deployed on your tablets for client authentication).